# Angular 9: forkJoin subscribe not working

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular9

I'm trying to load page data on a top level component in Angular 9 using observables (rxjs 6.5.1). When I subscribe to each of these services individually, I can see the data coming back just fine:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  const technicianSubscription = this.techniciansClientService.getByTechnicianId(this.technicianId).subscribe(technician => console.log(technician));
  const technicianReviewsSubscription = this.technicianReviewsClientService.getByTechnicianId(this.technicianId).subscribe(technicianReviews => console.log(technicianReviews));
}
```

When I try to use forkJoin, the data from the subscribe method is never returned:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.pageDataSubscription = forkJoin({
    technician: this.techniciansClientService.getByTechnicianId(this.technicianId),
    technicianReviews: this.technicianReviewsClientService.getByTechnicianId(this.technicianId),
  }).subscribe(
    // data is never logged here
    data => console.log(data)
  );
}
```

I've tried passing forkJoin an array of service calls and I've tried using zip as well, to no avail. What's happening here?

Comment: weird.. it looks it should work actually

Comment: Both the call `getByTechnicianId` are happening correctly? Check network console.

Comment: the behavior you describe can be achieved when one of the stream, or both of them emit events, but do not complete. forkJoin only emits an event whenever all of its sources are complete. could you check that version?

Comment: @Andrei I think this is what's happening. I tried putting a different service in forkJoin and it was successful. So it appears that the technician service call is not completing. Would you suggest using combineLatest like the answer below for my situation?

Comment: it depends on the situation you are trying to handle. could you provide an observable that technichian service returns? If it is too complicated I think `..getById(...).pipe(take(1))` taking just 1 event from this observable will handle the issue for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using `combineLatest` from `rxjs`. Its easier to use

```js
import {combineLatest} from `rxjs`;

componentIsActive = true;
ngOnInit(): void {
  combineLatest([
    this.techniciansClientService.getByTechnicianId(this.technicianId),
    this.technicianReviewsClientService.getByTechnicianId(this.technicianId),
  ]).pipe(
    map(([technician, technicianReviews]) => ({technician, technicianReviews})),
    takeWhile(() => this.componentIsActive)
  ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: This worked! Still digging through the docs to see what went wrong with forkJoin...

Comment: that also confirms the theory I proposed in the question comment. you should examine your situation and choose the best option

Comment: also a thing that would be useful for @Owen also - `takeWhile` way of unsubscribing is worse that the takeUntill one, as it will only unsubscribe when the event goes through this stream. That can cause memory leaks, if no event is emmited after component is destroyed. also it wouldn't cancel unneeded http requests if the component is destroyed before the response is downloaded

Comment: @Andrei thanks, I normally use either, mostly takeUntil but now i will stick to takeUntil

Comment: @EJMorgan, you has a type error using forkJoin, is `forkJoin(this.techniciansClientService.getByTechnicianId(..),this.technicianReviewsClientService.getByTechnicianId(..).subscribe(([technician, technicianReviews])=>{...})`